# Symmetric differences and measure theory.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Suppose that, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a measurable $F \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that
>   $$m_{\ast}(E \triangle F) < \epsilon.$$
>   Show that $E$ is measurable.

I need to show that:

> for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open $O$ with $E \subset O$ such that $m_{*}(O - E) \leq \epsilon$.

This question doesn't seem to require specific properties of measure theory. It seems viable to try to show that it is worth the definition. But I couldn't find a good way, maybe some specific property of symmetric differences would be useful.

I don't like the answer of the question, I just wanted a hint to try. Thanks for the advance!

Comment: Is $m_*$ an outer measure? Isn't the definition of $E$ being measurable then that
$m_*(A) = m_*(A \cap E) + m_*(A \cap E^c)$ for all sets $A$?

Comment: @md2perpe, $m_{*}$ is exterior measure. My book (Real Analysis - Stein) define $m(E) = m_{*}(E)$ when $E$ is measurable and the definition of measurable is the one I mentioned in the second block.

Comment: And $m_*$ is defined by $m_*(E) = \inf \sum_j |Q_j|$ where $Q_j$ are cubes such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_j Q_j$ and $|Q_j|$ is the volume of $Q_j$? (I found [the book](https://books.google.se/books?id=2Sg3Vug65AsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=real+analysis+stein&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV_svVwJHdAhVF2SwKHSwwBkIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=real%20analysis%20stein&f=false) on Google Books.)

Comment: Exactly! ${}$ $$

Comment: I missed that the cubes should be *closed*.

Comment: Of course! I didn't realize. Moreover, the covering can be by rectangles or balls, is not hard to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an open set $O \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying
$$m_{*}(O \setminus F) < \varepsilon,$$
because $F$ is measurable. Now we can use this in order to show that we also have $m_{*}( O \setminus E) < \varepsilon$.

In fact, note that $$O \setminus E \subset E \Delta F \cup O \setminus F.$$
This can be easily checked. Using the $\sigma$-subadditivity of the outer measure $m_{*}$ shows already that $m_{*}( O \setminus E) < \varepsilon$, as claimed.

However, we don't need to use the special properties of the Lebesgue-measure. The above statement is in general true for the "Carathéodory-$\sigma$-algebra" defined for an outer-measure. Let $\mu_{*}$ be any outer-measure on a set $X$. We need to prove that for an $Q \subset X$ the equality
$$\tag{1}\mu_{+}(Q) = \mu_{*}(E \cap Q) + \mu_{*}(Q \cap E^c).$$
holds. Since (1) is true for $F$ instead of $E$, it is enough to verify that
$\mu_{*}(F \cap Q) = \mu_{*}(E \cap Q)$, resp. $\mu_{*}(F^c \cap Q) = \mu_{*}(E^c \cap Q)$.

As above, we have $F \cap Q \subset E \cap Q \subset E \Delta F$ and also the same for $E$ replaced by $F$. Thus $\mu_{*}(F \cap Q) = \mu_{*}(E \cap Q)$. Similiar we can show that $\mu_{*}(F^c \cap Q) = \mu_{*}(E^c \cap Q)$.

Comment: The first inclusion follows from: if $x \in O - E$ and $x \not\in O - F$, so $x \in O, x \not\in E, x \in F$, then $x \in F - E$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @p4sch How do you guarantee in the first part of the prove that $E\subseteq O$?

Comment: We know that $F \subset O$ and that $E \Delta F \subset U$ for an open set $U$ with $m(U) < \varepsilon$. Take $O' = U \cup O$ as your open set. It satisfies $m_*(O' \setminus F) < \varepsilon$ and $F \subset E \cup E \Delta F \subset O \cup U = O'$.